# Does aws support s3 transfer acceleration across accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a s3 bucket in account A with the policy to give access to user in account B

I am able to sync the files across the account with

```
aws s3 sync [src] [dest]
```

I want to sync thousands of files and fast so I am using s3 transfer acceleration

Does AWS support it across accounts?

Update:
so I attempted it and I get errors like

```
An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the ListObjects operation: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'ap-northeast-1'
```

Without the transfer acceleration enabled, I am able to sync the two buckets across accounts without any problems

Comment: `aws s3 sync` shouldn't use/need/benefit from transfer acceleration, because the copy operation is done internally to S3 rather than via download + upload.  This could be an issue with the aws-cli (are you running the latest version?) or could be something else.  What region are src and dest buckets in?  Where are you running the sync command? On EC2? And in which region?  The fastest copy solution would require running it in EC2 in the same region as the target bucket, since this would reduce the round trip time between the cli and the API endpoint.

Comment: How did you use Transfer Acceleration with an `aws s3 sync` command? Also, use `--region` to send your command to the same region as the destination bucket. That might be what the errors was saying.

Comment: I have the cli version 1.10.46. The source bucket is in account A, AP tokyo region. The dest bucket is in account B, US east 1 region. I am running the sync command on my local machine to sync the buckets. I want to know if there are faster ways to synchronize buckets. I am doing it now with 200 concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure you're using the latest version of the AWS CLI. I had sporadic problems using the Ubuntu-supplied version.

The command you're looking for is something like this. Especially in situations where the regions use different S3 signature methods, you need to specify both the source and destination regions.

```
aws s3 sync \
  --source-region eu-west-1 \
  --region eu-central-1 \
  --endpoint-url https://s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com \
  s3://source-bucket-over-here/ \
  s3://destination-bucket-over-here/ \
```

I also configured the following in my ~/.aws/config file. Note that transfer-accelerated endpoints cannot be used by buckets with '.' in their names.

```
[default]
s3 =
    max_concurrent_requests = 2000
    max_queue_size = 1000
    addressing_style = virtual
```